# Docker connect swarm but return "err during connect xxxx EOF"

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

There is my command:

```
docker -H 192.168.99.99:3376 info
```

but result is, **this is come from `docker swarm join` way**:

```
Client:
Debug Mode: false

Server:
ERROR: error during connect: Get http://192.168.99.99:3376/v1.40/info: EOF
errors pretty printing info
```

there is my swarm info`docker node ls`:

```
ID                            HOSTNAME            STATUS              AVAILABILITY        MANAGER STATUS      ENGINE VERSION
6j937a34qsnlle33q2pf64fu7 *   centos              Ready               Active              Leader              19.03.4
bpak0b6sgrv594lf0opv9acgb     docker-desktop      Ready               Active                                  19.03.4
```

The normal info should to be this, **this is come from `docker run swarm join` way**:
[image]

Comment: What do you want to see? what info ?

Comment: @BatchenRegev This is my swarm address, I want see my container cluster.

Comment: try. `docker service ls` in manager node  if it doesn't answer you question please tell me exactly what you want to see.

Comment: I don't want service, I want docker run in swarm, `docker -H 192.168.99.99:3376 info`, should give me a swarm info json string, I post it to my question.